# PHP include without echo of data in mail function

Tags: php, email, include, return

I am using a PHP include function to add content to an email sent out. Problem is I don't want to echo the file too, I only want to include it as the $message.

Whats the equivalent of include that returns the string without the echo.

```
$message = include('email/head.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
ob_start();
include('email/head.php');
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `include` is to evaluate the included file as a PHP file. That means that anything outside of `<?php ?>` tags is considered output, and it's sent to the browser. If you want to get the content of a file, you need to read it using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)/[`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

If you want to evaluate the included file as executable PHP and capture the output, you should use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

**[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**
will put the full file contents into a variable.

```
<?php
// grabs your file contents
$email_head = file_get_contents('email/head.php');

// do whatever you want with the variable
echo $email_head ;
?>
```

Do take into consideration that it will not pre-process head.php as a `php` file. Therefore `file_get_contents()` is more suited for static text-files (templates).